# Why is this true for large enough n?

Tags: probability, inequality, asymptotics

> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \Pr[\text{bin } i \text{ has at least } k \text{ balls}] 
> &\leqslant \left( \frac{e}{k} \right)^k 
> = \left( \frac{e \ln \ln n}{3 \ln n} \right)^{\frac{3 \ln n}{\ln \ln n}}
> \\ &\leqslant \exp \left( \frac{3 \ln n}{\ln \ln n} (\ln \ln \ln n - \ln \ln n) \right)
> \\ &= \exp \left( - 3 \ln n +  \frac{3 \ln n \cdot \ln \ln \ln n}{\ln \ln n} \right)
> \end{align*}
> $$
>
> When $n$ is large enough,
>   $$
> \Pr[\text{bin } i \text{ has at least } k \text{ balls}] 
>  \leqslant \exp ( - 2 \ln n ) = \frac{1}{n^2}.
> $$

This was found in [this set of lecture notes](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/787-F09/scribe-notes/lec7.pdf).

Can anyone explain why the last step ("When n is large enough..") is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is that for large enough $n$, we have $3\ln (\ln(\ln(n))) < \ln(\ln(n))$ which is true since for large enough $m$, $3 \ln(m) < m$ and take $m = \ln(\ln(n))$. For instance, take $n \geq e^{e^5}$.

Since $3\ln (\ln(\ln(n))) < \ln(\ln(n))$, we have $$-3 \ln(n) + \frac{3 \ln (n) \ln (\ln(\ln(n)))}{\ln(\ln(n))} < -3 \ln(n) + \ln(n) = - 2 \ln(n).$$

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: What about that ln(n) multiplying 3ln(ln(ln(n)))/ln(ln(n))?

Comment: @Leo: That gets added to $-3\ln(n)$ to give $-2\ln(n)$.